# How do I change textarea's default border to light grey?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change textarea placeholder to a light grey but cannot seem to.

https://jsfiddle.net/mardystellar/pcvqgzuj/3/

Is there any way I can overwrite the user agent stylesheet? This is my first time dealing with css. I have only found answers to change the border when it is in focus but not in its default form.

```
<label for="" class="field_label">What</label>
<textarea placeholder="" id=""></textarea>
```

CSS

```
textarea {
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
}

textarea::placeholder {
    border-color: lightgrey;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of the textarea's border or the color of the text of the placeholder? Please clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

`border: solid 1px lightgrey`

```css
textarea {
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 1px lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<label for="" class="field_label">What</label>
<textarea placeholder="" id=""></textarea>
```

Comment: You show the syntax for border, but there is nothing wrong with just changing the border-color - especially if you want to keep all the other settings to what they have already been set as without necessarily knowing what they are.

Comment: @AHaworth Okay. i was confused. it was different at https://jsfiddle.net/mardystellar/pcvqgzuj/3/:
`textarea {
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1 px lightgrey;
}`

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't look at the fiddle, you are right that the space needs removing.

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of the placeholder text you can use the CSS property color in the :placeholder styling.

To change the color of the textarea's border you can use the CSS property border-color in the textarea stylings.

```css
textarea {
  resize: both;
  width: 100%;
  border-color: blue;
}

textarea::placeholder {
  border-color: lightgrey;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<label for="" class="field_label">What</label>
<textarea placeholder="this is the placeholder" id=""></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS code:
this changes, the font color in textarea

```
.textarea {
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1;
    color:lightgrey;
}
```

and this changes a border color of textarea

```
   .textarea {
    resize: both;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1;
    border-color:lightgrey;
}
```